# PHP/MongoDB & Complex Query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm pretty new in Mongodb. Just read documentation and played. I wanted to find documents with the word "MIA" and timestamp value between 25th Aug, 2014 to 28th Aug, 2014. I wrote this way

```
$var = "MIA";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$from = strtotime('2014-08-25');
$to = strtotime('2014-08-28');;

$var = new MongoRegex("/$var/");
$where1 = array( '$or' => array( array(array('caller' => $var)), array('callee' => $var)));

$where2 = array( '$and' => array( array('timestamp' => array('$gte' => $from )), array('timestamp' => array('$lte'=> $to)) ) );

$where = array( '$and' => $where1, $where2 );

//var_dump($where);

$cursor = $collection->find($where);
var_dump($cursor);
```

I was getting empty result. Can you please advice to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT:
Collection Structure
[image]

Comment: Can i see the collection structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$where1 = array(
    '$or' => array(
        // array(array('caller' => $var)) => often nest one
        array('caller' => $var),
        array('callee' => $var)
    )
);

$where2 = array(
    '$and' => array(
        array('timestamp' => array('$gte' => $from)),
        array('timestamp' => array('$lte'=> $to))
    )
);

// $where = array( '$and' => $where1, $where2 ); => `$where2` is not in $and query
$where = array( '$and' => array($where1, $where2));
```

Comment: Hmm. Is `var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));` output empty?

Comment: My bad, miss-typed one variable. However, worked. Thanks